# How to redirect the user to another page after they have logged in with Ion Auth CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have been working on admin panel of my project. I use Ion_Auth. I have a problem about redirecting after I have logged in on the system.

If I change default_controller as "auth", everything is okey and after I logged in, I have been redirecting to the user lists. But I have already a default_controller as "Home" and I don't want to change it as "Auth". If I change it as "Auth", login screen is shown first. If I use home as default_controller, when I have logged in on the system, Home page is shown instead of the page of user lists.

So I guess I need two default controllers one of them for my home page and also the other one for ion auth.

Any idea about the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In auth.php change the redirection route if user log in. That would be line 67 I guess. You need to play with ion_auth to set it fits your (application) needs.
I like to make parent controller in application/core that has checking function in constructor. All controllers that requires login part should extend that sort of controller. Google for phil sturgeon extending of MY_Controller.php to see what am I talking about.

Comment: Thank you man! You saved me. The line 67 is correct! I changed this     redirect('/', 'refresh');

Comment: No problem, thank you. Also, In my answer I pointed on that auth.php is (good) example controller and you can see and use code from it in any part of your code.

Comment: I will do what I need by following your directions. Thanks.